# VS Code terminal powerlevel10k theme icon is half cut

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, themes, iterm2

In my iTerm2 terminal, everything is fine including icons and fonts. But in my VS code terminal, the icons seem a little off. They are half cut in left and right. I have set up the proper terminal font in vs code. I am using "SourceCodePro+PowerLine+Awesome Regular" font. Mac os Monterey 12.2.1
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setting (JSON) fixed mine.

```
"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "canvas"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following settings in vscode's settings.json

```
{
"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hack Nerd Font"
}
```